# How do I use collected data from program?

Tags: c#

I have a program that is suppose to collect user car data in one method/class and then use it later.
In this case, user types in Year: 2001 Make: Mustang Model: GT (click Make the Car Button). The textboxes are cleared. Then click accelerate. In the DetailLabel it should increment speed by 5 every time the button is pressed. Output: The speed of 2001 Mustang GT is 5 mph. Same for the Brake Button. The speed of 2001 Mustang GT is 0 mph.

Problem: I can't access/use my collected data for brake or accelerate buttons.

Form1.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace CarMaker_Tate
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        private void GetCarData()
        {
            CarClass myCar = new CarClass();
            int CYear;
            string CMake = MakeTextBox.Text;
            String CModel = ModelTextBox.Text;
            if (int.TryParse(YearTextBox.Text, out CYear) && CYear >= 1900 && CYear <= 2022)
            {
                if (CMake != "")
                {
                    if (CModel != "")
                    {
                        myCar.Year = CYear;
                        myCar.Make = CMake;
                        myCar.Model = CModel;
                    }
                    else
                        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a car model");
                }
                else
                    MessageBox.Show("Please enter a car make");
            }
            else
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter a year between 1900 - 2022");
        }
    

        private void MakeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GetCarData();
            YearTextBox.Text = "";
            MakeTextBox.Text = "";
            ModelTextBox.Text = "";
        }

        private void AccelerateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            myCar.AccSpeed(5);
            DetailLabel.Text = "The speed of " + myCar.Year + myCar.Make + myCar.Model + "is" + myCar.Speed + "mph";
            
        }

        private void Summarybutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Summary mySummaryForm = new Summary();
            mySummaryForm.Show();
        }

        private void BrakeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            myCar.DecSpeed(5);
            DetailLabel.Text = "The speed of " + myCar.Year + myCar.Make + myCar.Model + "is" + myCar.Speed + "mph";
        }
    }
}
```

CarClass.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CarMaker_Tate
{
    class CarClass
    {
        int CarYear;
        string CarMake;
        string CarModel;
        public static int CarCount;

        public CarClass()
        {
            // constructor runs everytime a car is created
            CarYear = 0;
            CarMake = "";
            CarModel = "";
            CarCount++;
        }

        public int Year
        {
            get
            {
                return CarYear;
            }
            set
            {
                CarYear = value;
            }
        }

        public string Make
        {
            get { return CarMake; }
            set { CarMake = value; }
        }

        public string Model
        {
            get { return CarModel; }
            set { CarModel = value; }
        }
        public int Speed
        {
            get { return Speed; }
            set { Speed = value; }
        }

        public void AccSpeed(int speedIncrement)
        {
            //Add check for speed limit ranges
            Speed += speedIncrement;
        }

        public void DecSpeed(int speedDecrement)
        {
            //Add check for speed limit ranges
            Speed -= speedDecrement;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should declare myCar as a variable outside the GetCarData() method. Otherwise only the method GetCarData can access it. You can even think to make the variable static:

Like that:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    // declare myCar for the entire class
    private static CarClass myCar;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void GetCarData()
    {
        // init myCar
        myCar = new CarClass();

        ...
    }
}
```